# How can we conclude that $f$ resembles $1 -\frac 9 2 x^2 - \frac 1 2 y^2$ near $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I'm having some trouble understanding the following thing my teacher wrote:

> Let $f(x,y)=\cos(x + 2y) + \cos(2x + y)$, then: $$\text{hess}(f)|_{(0,0)}=\left(\begin{matrix} -5 & -4  \\ -4 & -5\end{matrix}  \right)$$
>
> The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $-9$ and an orthonormal eigenbasis is: $(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1,1),\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1,-1)) $.
>
> This means that locally, near the point $(0,0)$, the function $f$ resembles the function $1 -\frac 9 2 x^2 - \frac 1 2 y^2$.
>
> So we can conclude that the function $f$ has a local maximum at the point $0,0$.

I don't get how my teacher concluded that the function resembles the function  $1 -\frac 9 2 x^2 - \frac 1 2 y^2$ near the origin. How can I conclude that?

Comment: one mthod is to use the Taylor series for cosine, up to $\cos t = 1 - t^2/2...$   so, near the origina, your function is $$  1 - \frac{(x+2y)^2}{2} + 1  - \frac{(2x+y)^2}{2}$$   the resembled function might come from a change of coordinates, sensible would be $u = x+y$   and $v=x-y$

Comment: That's true! But why would he bring up the hessian matrix and the eigenbasis? Do you think that there is a way to deduce that from this information? @WillJagy

Comment: looking at your text again, everything is visible, including the change of variable....there are several ingredients. My suggestion is that you go through both methods, with his vatribles $u = (x+y)/ \sqrt 2, \; \; $  $ v = (x-y) / \sqrt 2  $, until you can see how it all works out. Note $x = (u+v)/ \sqrt 2, \; \; $  $ y = (u-v) / \sqrt 2  $

Comment: The elliptic paraboloid $z=1-\frac{9}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2$ cannot possibly resemble the graph of $f$ near the origin. This elliptic paraboloid intersects the $z-$ axis at $(0,0,1)$ while $z=f(x,y)$ intersects the $z-$axis at $(0,0,2)$ so something isn't right here.